# Deisgn a comparator for Oracle blob

Tags: java, comparison, soa

I'm having a problem where I've to do a comparison between Oracle blobs with some text files. And this needs to be designed in a service-oriented manner so that in future we can add a UI on top of this and the UI will display the difference (as of now we will email the differences). Could someone help with what technologies and design strategies that might be used for this (or any other pointers) ? We are a Java shop.

Thanks
Yana

Comment: I think http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is better for this type of question.  However I think you need to be much more specific about your requirements before anyone could answer.

Comment: thanks - can you tell me what kind of reqs you are looking for - its a difference generator between a blob and a text file (and the design needs to be service-oriented) - that's all I know now.

Comment: Well, "service-oriented" isn't well defined, I have no idea what you are looking for.  And I think your UI requirements need to be defined as well, otherwise why even mention them?  What format is your UI looking for?  (Take a look at https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/ ).

Comment: I want an application that can compare two datasources and output a difference report. Can I keep the design flexible enough so that I can put any view to visualize the differences e.g. my UI can be a simple angular view.